# String distance metrics that is in favor of substring, and word order independent?

Tags: r, string, edit-distance, stringdist

For my data analytics problem, I usually needs to regulate names, that names A, and B, I'd consider them the same or very similar, if A and B share substantial number of common substrings, regardless of the order of those substring.

For example, for "COLD", and c("FLOOD", "COLD/WIND CHILL"), I'd like to choose "COLD/WIND CHILL" to be much more similar to "COLD" than with "FLOOD".

My current assignment is in R. So my concrete questions are the following:

1. Is there such metrics already defined in R?
2. Is it possible to provide my own implementation and somehow integrate with R's stringdist package?

For my requirement, I could simply use regular expression search as long as I could find A in B or B in A, I may just consider their distance to be 0.

Thanks a lot!

Edit:

In the context of the following:

```
> vv <- c("FLOOD", "COLD/WIND CHILL")
> sapply(vv, adist, y = "COLD")
          FLOOD COLD/WIND CHILL 
              3              11
```

I wish the distance from "COLD" to "COLD/WIND CHILL" would be smaller than "COLD" to "FLOOD".

It seems that the metrics has to ignore the remaining part to be deleted, after finding the matched substring.

Edit1:

My original problem has been solved. Here is a follow up with related problem of using `amatch` of `stringdist` in R:

It seems to me that I was not able to reproduce the equivalent result of those with `adist`, and even `stringdist` in the same package with `amatch`.

Below is the illustration:

```
vv <- c("FLOOD", "COLD/WIND CHILL")
sapply(vv, adist, y = "COLD",costs=list(deletions=0))
          FLOOD COLD/WIND CHILL 
              2               0 

    stringdist("COLD", c("FLOOD", " COLD/WIND CHILL"), method = 'lv', weight=c(0.001, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99))
[1] 1.981 1.002

amatch("COLD", c("FLOOD", " COLD/WIND CHILL"), method = 'lv', weight=c(0.0001, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999), maxDist = 100)
[1] 1
```

In the above context, by using the computation of `stringdist`, `amatch` should return `2`, instead of `1`.

Based on the document of stringdist,

"weight:
For method='osa' or 'dl', the penalty for deletion, insertion, substitution and transposition, in that order. When method='lv', the penalty for transposition is ignored. "

I have chosen the weights accordingly to remove penalty to deletion, while maxing the penalty to the other operations. It's encouraging that `stringdist` shows the expected behavior with the weights setting.

I'd assume that `amatch` would use `stringdist` to do the calculation, but it seems strange the behavior of `amatch` contradicts with the behavior of `stringdist`!

I wish to get `amatch` working so that I don't have to re-implement it using `adist` or `stringdist`.

Thanks for help again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `adist` for fuzzy distance. The distance is a generalized Levenshtein distance.

```
vv <- c("COLD","FLOOD")
sapply(vv,adist,y="COLD/WIND CHILL")
## COLD FLOOD   
##  11    13    ## the distance to COLD < distance to FLOOD
```

#### edit after OP update:

You can play with `costs` parameter to set how you wan the distance to be computed in terms of : deletions,substitutions, insertions . Here for example:

```
sapply(vv, adist, y = "COLD",costs=list(deletions=0))
  FLOOD COLD/WIND       CHILL 
          2               0
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried in my context, it still does not solve my problem. Please see my edits above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one direction to pursue.  Basically, it intends to break up your text into trigrams (sequences of three letter) and return associations between each trigram and all others if they reach the level you set (here, 0.8).  The glitch is that this code works only at the word level, not at trigrams as it is supposed to.  Perhaps if the text file were larger there would be a difference?

```
library(tm)
library("RWeka")
text <- c("FLOOD", "COLD/WIND CHILL", "OLD", "FRIGID", "FLOW") 

BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 3, max = 3))

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))

lapply(tdm$dimnames$Terms, function(x) findAssocs(tdm, x, 0.8))
```